# Db Name as parameter in stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, where-clause

I'm looking to pass my database name as a parameter to the stored procedure, and I'm looking to use it in the where condition to set the database of the stored procedure. But I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

Sample Code

```
Create proc [dbo].[stored_procedure_one]
    @variable1 int,
    @dbname varchar(10)
as
begin
    select * 
    from @dbname..table_name
End
```

Can someone suggest me how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use dynamic sql for this something like this.....

```
Create proc [dbo].[stored_procedure_one]
    @variable1 int,
    @dbname    SYSNAME  --<-- use appropriate data type for object names
as
begin
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @Sql = N' select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'..table_name'

 Exec sp_executesql @Sql

End
```

Also use `QUOTENAME()` function to protect yourself against possible sql-injection attack.

Comment: Yes this should solve the issue. The call of `sp_executesql` isn't necessary. You can call 'EXEC(@sql)` too.

Comment: @Ionic there is an extra variable in the procedure definition, I am assuming that, this is not the whole code but only part of the code where OP is having problem, using `sp_executesql` allows you to use parametrised queries hence the sp_executesql in my answer :)

Comment: Well for parametrize it would be ok yes. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative, it's fun to note that `EXEC` can take a string as the thing to execute, so for example:

```
DECLARE @sp nvarchar(255) = N'sys.sp_who2';
EXEC @sp;
```

It can also take parameters, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sp nvarchar(255) = N'sys.sp_who2';
EXEC @sp 'active';
```

So we can dynamically build the context where we run a command by using:

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname = N'tempdb';
DECLARE @context nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@dbname)
  + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT DB_NAME();';

EXEC @context @sql;
```

And you can pass parameters, too:

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname = N'tempdb';
DECLARE @context nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@dbname)
  + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT DB_NAME(), @x;';

EXEC @context @sql, N'@x int', 5;
```

This approach really simplifies things like concatenating the database name all over the place, avoiding db-specific functions like object_name, and ensures that your entire command *runs in that other database*. You can also do it across linked servers, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @server sysname = N'linked_server';
DECLARE @dbname sysname = N'tempdb';
DECLARE @context nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@server)
  + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@dbname)
  + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
...
```